# prolog clp label - ignore some variable?

Tags: prolog, clpz

My base definition

```
use_module(library(clpfd)).
/* base definitions */
ice_cream(vanilla).
ice_cream(chocolate).
ice_cream(strawberry).
```

Turn words into integers

```
/*get falavor position */
icecream_index(Icecream,Icecreamlist,Start,End) :-
    var(Icecream),
    Icecream in Start .. End.
icecream_index(Icecream,Icecreamlist,Start,End) :-
    \+ var(Icecream),
    nth0(StartEnd,Icecreamlist,Icecream),
    Icecream is StartEnd,
    Icecream in StartEnd .. StartEnd.
```

Main program that generates all combinations

```
/* generate all combinations of ice cream */
icecream_menu(MenuList) :-
    MenuList = [Toppingone, Toppingtwo, Toppingthree],
    findall(X,ice_cream(X),Icecreamlist),

    length(Icecreamlist, Icecreamcount),

    Icecreamstart is 1,
    Icecreamend is Icecreamcount,

    icecream_index(Toppingone,Icecreamlist,Icecreamstart,Icecreamend),
    icecream_index(Toppingtwo,Icecreamlist,Icecreamstart,Icecreamend),
    icecream_index(Toppingthree,Icecreamlist,Icecreamstart,Icecreamend),

    all_different(MenuList),
    label(MenuList).
```

When I call MenuList(X), giving empty variable it is able to generate all possible combinations, however when I give it a list, `MenuList([vanilla, X, Y])` it just fails when it should generate all combinations of ice cream topping starting with vanilla.

A second problem I can't figure out it how to turn the integer to words, so instead of getting Menu = [1, 2, 3] I want to get Menu = [vanilla, chocolate, strawberry].

Comment: try `icecream_menu(MenuList) :- findall(T,ice_cream(T),Ts),permutation(Ts,MenuList).`

Comment: that is a solution, but want to do it with clp(fd), also when  `icecream_menu([vanilla,X,Y]).` is called, does not return it as a list